# Android in-app billing SDK V3 : Error refreshing inventory

Tags: android, sdk, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I'm getting an exception:

```
com.android.vending.billing.util.IabException: Error refreshing inventory (querying prices of items). (response: 6:Error)
```

on

```
(IabHelper instance).queryInventory(true, skuList);
```

on 2 devices of 4 (different manufacturers, android os versions), on other 2 it works okay. skuList is populated ok

Whay does it mean and how can it be fixed/walk-around?

Answer (score 1):

I'm only seeing that in my implementation if a device doesn't have a network connection. Are the 2 devices that failed connected to the carrier network or wi-fi?

Comment: I actually tested this and posted something about this too. See if what I posted helps you out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15471131/in-app-billing-v3-unable-to-query-items-without-network-connection-or-in-airplan/15471951#15471951

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error message, in my case I was a total idiot and passed the Base64-encoded RSA public key (used in the setup of IabHelper) in the SKU list. When I changed that to the actual in-app product id, the problem disappeared.