# In-app billing v3 unable to query items without network connection or in airplane/flight mode

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, in-app-purchase

Going through the v3 example file in modifying it with my project works fine. However my friend just tested the code by turning wi-fi off and turning on airplane mode. This seems to result in not being able to query the in-app inventory.

```
// Listener that's called when we finish querying the items and subscriptions we own
private final IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener mGotInventoryListener = new IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onQueryInventoryFinished(IabResult result, Inventory inventory) {

        if (result.isFailure()) {
            // STOPS here and doesn't continue on with no network connection
            return;
        }

        ......
    }
};
```

I thought that after a initial successful purchase that v3 stores that locally in it's cache so that it didn't always have to have a network connection to check. Has anyone else ran into this issue? I hope I'm missing something completely obvious or if this is how it's supposed to work.

Comment: I just tried it. If flight mode/airplane mode or testing on a device that's just using a wi-fi connection that's turned off, then I'm not able to query the inventory. Wondering if anyone else is running into this issue

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think I may have found the answer. In following v3's TrivialDriveExample I was calling the queryInventoryAsync function in the mHelper.startSetup() function like so:

```
Log.d(TAG, "Setup successful. Querying inventory.");
mHelper.queryInventoryAsync(mGotInventoryListener);
```

Instead now I'm passing a String array list of my SKUs that I want to query for:

```
List<String> skulist = new ArrayList<String>();
skulist.add("my_sku_name1");
skulist.add("my_sku_name2");
mHelper.queryInventoryAsync(true, skulist, mGotInventoryListener);
```

I then tested by turning on flight mode and I was able to query my purchases fine!

Comment: I am having the same problem.. Only it happens at my mobile with connection. If i clean the data and try again there is no problem. 
But when the application is closed and reopend it seems to have the same problem.  I'm passing the skyList as specified above.. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure then since I was only running into the problem without a network connection. If you just try using mHelper.queryInventoryAsync(mGotInventoryListener); do you get the same results?

Comment: I'm experiencing the same problem. The weird thing is that I have about 10 apps that are based on the exact same library that I wrote and that uses IabHelper. 9 of them work, while one doesn't. I really have no clue as to how to solve this.

Comment: This happens to me. Using the same code, it succeeds every time on five different devices, but fails almost every time on just one device (a Note 2). Any ideas what the cause is? Seems like a network-related error but I can't find the trigger.

Comment: @jmrmb80 That's not work for me! Even this: mHelper.queryInventoryAsync(false, mGotInventoryListener);

Answer (score 2):

Problem is, that in your first approach, the API do not know what SKUs exist and per default (the single param version) is trying to query that list. In airplane mode this is not possible - either because it does not cache a list of skus or there is some internal error preventing it from finishing.

You can either send in a list of SKUs you want to query (like you did later on) or you can just supress the online query for sku list.

```
helper.queryInventoryAsync(false, yourListener);
```

*credits to: jmrmb80*

It depends more likely if you need this information (i.e. displaying prices in your app).

(see the other overloads for that function or already given answers. Most likely you don't need the SKUs for checking if a purchase was made I think, so I would go for the answer of jmrmb80 - for me this solved the problem of not recognizing a purchase in airplane mode

Answer (score 1):

For me the following bit worked ...

> mHelper.queryInventoryAsync(false, mGotInventoryListener);

instead of

> mHelper.queryInventoryAsync(mGotInventoryListener);

I found it in another link [a Error refreshing iventory (querying prices of items). (response: 6:Error)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21539639/1369065)

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem that away:

```
final ArrayList<String> iabItemSkus = new ArrayList<String>();
iabItemSkus.add(MyGame.productID_FULLVERSION);

// Disable SKU details if no network connection
boolean checkSkuDetails = isWifiConnected() ? true : false;

Gdx.app.log("IAB", "checkSkuDetails : " + checkSkuDetails);

mHelper.queryInventoryAsync(checkSkuDetails, iabItemSkus, mGotInventoryListener);
```

Not get Sku details if not network.