# Failed to query inventory : Error refreshing inventory

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I don't understand why i keep getting the following message when i am starting my app:

> Error: Failed to query inventory: IabResult: Error refereshing
>   inventory (querying prices of items). (response:6:Error)

I observed that if there is network connection available then i don't receive the error message and it also doesn't appear for some time after i close the network connection. But say after few hours again the message starts popping up if there is no network !

Any idea to get around this issue ? Does caching comes in picture over here ? Is there some kind of timeout involved ? Should we simply not show the error if the querying fails ?

**EDIT**:

I have installed the app on my device by logging in with a test account. I have purchased the in-app feature as well.

Is this issue because its a test account ?

Any help would be great.

Thanks,
Adithya.

Comment: This isn't a direct answer to your question, but I should add that this error message can also happen if there isn't a valid google account on the phone.

Answer (score 2):

In my testing I was running across the same issue with no network connection. See my answer here to see if the same thing happens:

[In-app billing v3 unable to query items without network connection or in airplane/flight mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15471131/in-app-billing-v3-unable-to-query-items-without-network-connection-or-in-airplan/15471951#15471951)

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error message, in my case I was a total idiot and passed the Base64-encoded RSA public key (used in the setup of IabHelper) in the SKU list. When I changed that to the actual in-app product id, the problem disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void onIabSetupFinished(IabResult result) {
    if (result.isSuccess()) {
      
        iabHelper.queryInventoryAsync(false,this);
    } else {
        showError("err");
    }

}
```

> i have this problem so be ok when add false in              iabHelper.queryInventoryAsync(false,this);