# Error refreshing iventory (querying prices of items). (response: 6:Error)

Tags: android

I'm facing exactly same problem as

[In-app billing v3 unable to query items without network connection or in airplane/flight mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15471131/in-app-billing-v3-unable-to-query-items-without-network-connection-or-in-airplan/15471951#15471951)

It don't always occur. You need to switch your phone to airplane mode, or turn off wifi, wait for several hour, only the problem will occur. The following error message will be shown.

> Failed to query iventory : IabResult: Error refreshing iventory
>   (querying prices of items). (response: 6:Error)

Author suggested using

```
List<String> skulist = new ArrayList<String>();
skulist.add("my_sku_name1");
skulist.add("my_sku_name2");
mHelper.queryInventoryAsync(true, skulist, mGotInventoryListener);
```

to solve the problem.

However, it doesn't work for me. Same problem still occur.

Any workaround on this problem? Thanks.

Comment: I have only a very cursory familiarity with the IabHelper class (from another SO question), so this is essentially a stab in the dark. Try this call instead: `mHelper.queryInventoryAsync(false, null, mGotInventoryListener);` (or, equivalently, `mHelper.queryInventoryAsync(false, mGotInventoryListener);`).

Comment: Did you solved your problem?!

Comment: Nope. I simply read the in-app purchase status, which is being stored previously, when network connection is failed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As Jerry suggested in his comment, you can work around this by calling

> mHelper.queryInventoryAsync(false, mGotInventoryListener);

instead of

> mHelper.queryInventoryAsync(mGotInventoryListener);

I have disabled all network connectivity from my device (for over a day) and can reliably reproduce/fix the issue with that single parameter change. Looks like the purchase itself will be cached for longer (indefinitely?) by the in-app billing service than the sku details like price.

Comment: But now you don't fetch for the skuDetails, which you might want to have. Keep that in mind.

Comment: That's not work for me! ------ Even mHelper.queryInventoryAsync(true, skuList, mGot) ------- Even mHelper.queryInventoryAsync(false, skuList, mGot) .

Answer (score 3):

It looks like Google Play has expiration of cached inventory items. That may be implementation detail of how Google Play app works.

Error 6 is defined as BILLING_RESPONSE_RESULT_ERROR.

If it's critical for you to offer inventory for purchase even without Internet connection, you may need to **cache last returned results yourself**, and use them in case that querying fails.

However, purchasing also would not work in such scenario, so why to bother?

Comment: Based on the linked question, I read the OP's problem as displaying items that have already been bought, not offering new items for sale. In that case, caching them yourself is more useful (assuming the results do indeed expire; I have no idea if that's true or not).