# Failed to query inventory without internet connection

Tags: android, in-app-billing

I update IAB Helper from TrivialDrive in my app. QueryInventoryFinishedListener start get result.isFailure() if no internet connection. In earlier version of IAB Helper everything works fine without result.isFailure() even if no internet connection for a weeks.

It is a feature of new version of IAB Helper or I'm doing wrong something?

`IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener mGotInventoryListener = new IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener() {
        public void onQueryInventoryFinished(IabResult result, Inventory inventory) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Query inventory finished.");`

```
        if (mHelper == null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "null: " + result);
            return;
        }

        if (result.isFailure()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Failed to query inventory: " + result);
            return;
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "Query inventory was successful.");
        Purchase proPurchase = inventory.getPurchase(SKU_PRO);
        mIsPro = (proPurchase != null);`
```

Comment: What message is printed in the log?

Comment: Failed to query inventory: IabResult: Error refreshing inventory (querying prices of items). (response: 6:Error)

Comment: add this line: `mHelper.enableDebugLogging(true)` and filter with this tag: `IabHelper`.

Comment: `D: Checking for in-app billing 3 support.

D: In-app billing version 3 supported for com.antonnikitin.app
D: Subscription re-signup AVAILABLE.
D: Starting async operation: refresh inventory
D: Querying owned items, item type: inapp
D: Package name: com.antonnikitin.app
D: Calling getPurchases with continuation token: null
D: Owned items response: 0
D: Sku is owned: fh.solunar.pro
D: Continuation token: null
D: Querying SKU details.
D: getSkuDetails() failed: 6:Error
D: Ending async operation: refresh inventory`

Comment: OMG! How to make new line?

Comment: check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15471131/in-app-billing-v3-unable-to-query-items-without-network-connection-or-in-airplan/15471951#15471951

Comment: I check this. In my code I use sku list in mHelper.queryInventoryAsync.

Comment: I suppose error showing because of `querying prices of items`. I did not ask prices manually, but it looks like prices querying automatically.

Comment: Try adding: `boolean checkSkuDetails = isWifiConnected() ? true : false;` and passing that as the first parameter to `queryInventoryAsync`

Comment: Bingo! I don't need to check sku details at all. Just set false in queryInventoryAsync. Thank you!)))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In-app Billing service, that the IabHelper talks to, caches the purchase history and is able to query the inventory offline. But some options (like not providing the list of target SKUs or requesting SKU details) enforce the service to talk to the server, which is not possible without internet connection. So, if you want to be able to query the inventory offline, do it this way:

```
boolean querySkuDetails = isNetworkAvailable();
mHelper.queryInventoryAsync(querySkuDetails, skuList, this);
```